# MongoDB / PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm running a script that scrapes a quite large amount of data, and then use a function to upload that data to mongodb. I keep getting hit by connection closed errors and can't figure out why it happens, as the data gets chunked in 5000 sets every time, but when I only run 15.000 sets, it runs fine. When I run 50.000 sets I get `pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: scrapy-01-lb.3vs0u.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer`

```
def insertData (data, collection):
    try:
        client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://admin:password@url.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&socketTimeoutMS=360000&connectTimeoutMS=360000", server_api=ServerApi('1'))
        collection.drop()
        if data != []:
            chunks = [data[x:x+5000] for x in range(0, len(data), 5000)]
            for i in chunks:
                print(collection.insert_many(i))
```

How to solve this error? by throwing a retry under except `pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect as e:` continuously?

Comment: Isn't `i` a single document?

Answer (score 0):

Error solved by

```
except pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect as e:
collection.insert_many(i)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).